# How to track changes in a service in Angular4

Tags: angular, onchange, watch

please how can I track / watch a variable or an array that's in a service to detect if it's value has been changed or an item has been added???

Comment: Add some code to your post or you won't find much help I'm afraid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is what you expect in the end from "track / watch".
You can, for example, put your variable inside a Subject or BehaviorSubject. Then subscribe to it. Whenever now changes happen to this Subject you'll get informed.

Here is an example.

Your Service provides the variable 'info' which is put inside a BehaviorSubject. You access this variable via getters and setters. Please note that the getter returns an Observable which is important for monitoring changes.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private info = new BehaviorSubject('information');

  getInfo(): Observable<string> {
    return this.info.asObservable();
  }

  getInfoValue(): string {
    return this.info.getValue();
  }

  setInfo(val: string) {
    this.info.next(val);
  }
}
```

And in your component you do the following

```
import { MyService } from 'my.service';

constructor(
    private myService: MyService
) { 

    /**
     * whenever your variable info inside the service changes
     * this subscription will get an event and immediately call the code
     * inside.
     */
    this.myService.getInfo().subscribe(value => {
        // do something with this value
        console.log('Info got changed to: ', value);
    });
}
```

That's the best way to monitor changes on a variable inside a service.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a perfect answer. Another question I have is. I am trying to update the location field in a Mongodb database when there is a change in the position of the device. Now, I'm using ionic Google map. But seeing how very little movement causes lots of changes in the location value. Wouldn't it be too much bombarding the server with a call to update its value all the time??

Comment: I agree. This would tend to cause a lot of unnecessary network traffic. I'd suggest you to browse through the documentation of the whole rxjs framework as there are a lot of possibilities to work with timers and delays to regulate and control this behavior.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks a billion. You've been so much help